# How do I get my public ip address in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, networking, dns, dig

This command returns my ip address with additional information.

```
dig @resolver1.opendns.com myip.opendns.com
; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @resolver1.opendns.com myip.opendns.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48206
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION: 
;myip.opendns.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myip.opendns.com.   0   IN  A   122.167.119.178

;; Query time: 199 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Fri May 18 11:46:51 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50
```

I only want to extract my ip address from this. How can I extract my ip address from the `dig` output?

Comment: the following works for me  "dig @resolver1.opendns.com myip.opendns.com  | grep ^myip.opendns.com | tr  '\t' : | cut -d: -f5"

Answer (score 15):

Don't make this harder than it needs to be... use `+short`

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig +short mike.homeunix.com
76.21.48.169
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bash shell this will work for you

```
grep -A1 "ANSWER SECTION" ip_file.txt  | awk '{if(NF==5)print $5;}'
```

NOTE: My assumption is you are planning to extract the ip printed after the "ANSWER SECTION"

Answer (score 1):

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

From my blog: http://blog.valch.name/2016/03/17/show-your-ip/

Comment: Why do you wanna use a shortener? Moreover, this is supposed to be a shell script, not a URL.

Comment: because the result should be with only IP address, without additional info, that why I use it. Moreover,  this is a shell command and supposed to be a command, not a script. URL just for an example of usage.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is:

```
sudo apt install stuntman-client
```

then

```
myip=$(stunclient --localport 8888 stun.l.google.com 19302|grep Mapped|cut -d ":" -f 2|tr -d " ")
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04,
`sudo apt install stun;
myip=$(stun stun.l.google.com -v 2>&1 | grep MappedAddress | cut -d: -f1 | awk '{print $NF}' | head -1)`